# Any solution to the giant list of unwind segues for table cell clicks?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

I had to control+drag from every cell to the `Exit Segue` to make every cell click to take me back to the previous View. There's got to be a better way right? If there isn't a better way to set them up, can I at least group them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: why don't you just call the segue in didSelectRow

Comment: In code you can just override `tableView:didSelectRow:atIndexPath:` with `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES]`.

Comment: Also, are these all different prototype cells? You should only need to create one prototype cell of each type. You shouldn't create a separate prototype cell for each cell you want in the table view.

Comment: @AdamPro13 I added an additional image to show you the cells. Am I doing the cells wrong? I'm not sure what a prototype cell is. Any resources to link to to describe the alternate way of doing it?

Comment: @Corey yes, I am pretty sure you are doing this incorrectly. You do not need to add a table view cell to the table view for each row you want to display. I'm going to assume for now that you only have 1 type of cell. You create one cell in the storyboard and give it an identifier. You then implement the `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method and `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` methods. These methods will automatically create however many cells you tell it to to & return those cells.

Comment: I should also clarify that the table view won't immediately create all of the cells. It will only create as many as it can display, and will then reuse those cells to save memory. Let me know if you have any other questions on how this is implemented.

Comment: I'm a Front-End Web Developer by trade so I'm used to building interfaces directly. Not writing logic to loop and build them. I was trying to build everything out from the Storyboard builder. Add every table, Row, Image, Button. Do you mostly do this type of work through the code? If so, how do you make the storyboard view reflect this?